# Recursively delete files from a Directory but keeping the dir structure intact

Tags: c#, .net, linq, file, linq-to-objects

For cleaning up the test files, am trying to do the below. But its not clearing the files as well as not generating an error.

Am I missing something obvious?

```
    private void CleanUpTempDirFiles()
    {
        var fileGenerationDir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "TestFilesDir"));

        fileGenerationDir.GetDirectories().ToList().ForEach(dir => dir.GetFiles().ToList().ForEach(file => file.Delete()));
    }
```

Comment: Try out the debugger. It helps you determine what the program does at runtime. That's much better than just *looking* at the code trying to see the bug.

Comment: isn't this code sample deleting files in your subfolders?  Or you want to delete files in your main file?

Comment: That's not entirely recursive. It will only delete (in theory) the files in the directories directly under the top level directory. Is that the intention?

Comment: Your code is only deleting files from the sub-directories. You need to do => fileGenerationDir.GetFiles().ToList().ForEach(file => file.Delete());

Comment: @wdavo: Agreed! I want to delete from all the sub-dirs. I've done the change as suggested by Tilak and that works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get all the files in all the the subdirectories using [SearchOption.AllDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx)

```
 fileGenerationDir.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList().ForEach(file=>file.Delete());
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(
            Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "TestFilesDir")
            , 
            "*", 
            SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
            File.Delete(filePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `GetDirectories` first which returns all sub-directories in your temp folder. Hence it does not return the files in this directory. So you might want to do this instead:

```
var tempDir = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "TestFilesDir");
var allFilesToDelete = Directory.EnumerateFiles(tempDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in allFilesToDelete)
    File.Delete(file);
```

Removed the `ToLists` and used `SearchOption.AllDirectories` which searches recursively.

[**How to: Iterate Through a Directory Tree (C# Programming Guide)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If files are stored inside the TestFilesDir folder you don't have to get it's subdirectories, use simply:

```
fileGenerationDir.GetFiles().ToList().ForEach(file => file.Delete());
```

otherwise you are deleting only subfolder's files

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CleanUpTempDirFiles() {
        var fileGenerationDir = new DirectoryInfo(
            Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "TestFilesDir"));

        fileGenerationDir.GetFiles().ToList().ForEach(file => file.Delete());            
    }
```